# What should be the format of the WSDL file used in SOAP-REST connector?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I have WSDL file in XML format but I am not able to select it.

Comment: It should be a file with ".wsdl" but not ".xml"

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL file can be of XML format but make sure the selected file is in .wsdl extension. It works fine for me.
[.wsdl file imported/selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwqqe.png)